# Why cookie not being set in browser, but it does in POSTMAN?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cookies

I am sending a GET request for Basic authentication, to which the server(the backend API) would return(if the authentication is successful) a cookie. This is working fine for POSTMAN, but in browser cookie is not being set.

```
@GetMapping("/login")
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public void loginUser( final HttpServletRequest request ,final HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        setAuthCookieToResonse(request,response);    
    }

private void setAuthCookieToResonse(final HttpServletRequest request ,final HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    logger.debug("Adding cookie after authentication");
    String cookieKey = "auth";
    String cookieValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    if (cookieValue != null) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieKey, URLEncoder.encode(cookieValue, "utf-8"));
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setDomain("localhost");

        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

Here is my application flow:

1. Browser/POSTMAN login using basic authentication. Send credentials
   using `Authorization Basic xxxxxx==` header.
2. Server reads the authentication details, and if correct it creates a
   cookie named `auth` and send it back with the response(above code).
   For security layer, I am using Spring security.
3. For further requests, that cookie will automatically be sent with
   each request. Now I had to take that cookie and extract the
   authentication details from that. After that, I had to add
   `Authorization Basic xxxxxx==` to that request(Because now the
   `Authorization` not sent by the client, only cookie sent). For this
   I created the `Filter` which will run before Spring's
   `BasicAuthenticationFilter.class`

The step 2 is working for POSTMAN, but not for the browser. In POSTMAN, the server sent `response` contains `Set-Cookie →auth=Basic xxxxxxxx=; Domain=localhost; HttpOnly`.

```
curl -i -u pu@gmail.com:password@ http://localhost:8085/api/v1/login

HTTP/1.1 200
Set-Cookie: auth=Basic xxxxxxxx==; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 05:59:33 GMT
```

The response header in browser:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3007
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 11:52:10 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

What additional configuration do I need to do here?

Comment: Browser does not send `Authorization` header until server asks for it. With POSTMAN, you've probably told it to send the header *preemptively*, i.e. unsolicited by the server, so that's why it works there. Browser will send `Authorization` header on a second request after receiving a `401 Unauthorized` with a `WWW-Authenticate` header from the server. Is your server configured to do that?

Comment: @Andreas I have added the application flow. Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Could you also add raw http response you are getting in the browser?

Comment: @Ilya updated. please have a look.

Comment: Seems you didn't understand my comment. The browser will not send `Authorization` header unless prompted by the *server*. Look at the headers in the browser request to see whether it actually sends `Authorization` header or not. --- Also, when using BASIC authentication, there is usually no explicit `/logon` URL, since any webapp URL can do the login. Normal flow is: 1) Browser sends GET to `/foo`. 2) Server sends `401 Unauthorized`. 3) Browser prompts user for password. 4) Browser re-sends GET to `/foo` with Auth header. 5) Server verifies password and processes the `/foo` request.

Comment: 1. Yes, It does send`Authorization` header with the request which carries the user credentials(the 1st step as above). The cookie I am using, just to make sure that I don't need to add `Authorization` header to **each** request to the server. Since browser will send them automatically with each request.

Comment: @Andreas To the Basic auth you said: Yes there is no concept of login in Basic auth. But I made it to keep my user logged in, by using the cookie. Still credentials are getting sent to the server with each request, but in the cookie. I just added a login form, so that when first Basic auth request gets to the server, it returns a cookie to the client which will then be carried with each request.

Comment: If the browser doesn't send Authorization header why do you expect the server to return cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You have to append `withCredentials` to the http calls you make from the browser or else the browser won't response the `Set-Cookie` header.

**Angular example**

```js
return this.http.post(url, userLoginRequest, { withCredentials: true }) as Observable<
      LoginResponse
>
```

**Axios example**

```
axios.post(API_SERVER + '/login', { email, password }, { withCredentials: true })
```

**XMLHttpRequest example**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/', true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```